# Is there some way to have Newtonsoft.Create call your custom creation method on an interface?

Tags: c#, interface, json.net, deserialization, hangfire

I am using `Hangfire` to run multiple tasks of my custom `interface`, let's call it `IType`. However, since `Hangfire` serializes the method, thereby destroying the instance of that type so when it tries to call it I get an error message like this:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not create an instance of type IType. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'Something', line 1, position 17.
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(...

I figure that one way around this is for each `class` that is an instance of my `interface` can store its `fully qualified domain name`, then I can use `reflection` to return it the type that it needs, only problem is I don't know how to get `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject()` to call my deserialization method. Is there some `attribute` or some specific method name I need to have in order to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a `JsonSerializerSettings` that includes a suitable `TypeNameHandling` value. That will embed the fully qualified name in the JSON in a `$type` property, which it can then use to deserialize. Here's a complete example:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

interface IFoo
{
    void Method();
}

class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public void Method() => Console.WriteLine("Method in Foo1");
}

class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public void Method() => Console.WriteLine("Method in Foo2");
}

class Root
{
    public IFoo First { get; set; }
    public IFoo Second { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Root root = new Root
        { 
            First = new Foo1 { Name = "Fred" },
            Second = new Foo2 { Value = 10 }
        };
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, settings);

        Console.WriteLine(json);

        Root root2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json, settings);
        root2.First.Method();
        root2.Second.Method();
    }
}
```

Output, showing both the JSON and the fact that the interface properties in `Root` have been suitably deserialized:

```
{"$type":"Root, Test","First":{"$type":"Foo1, Test","Name":"Fred"},"Second":{"$type":"Foo2, Test","Value":10}}
Method in Foo1
Method in Foo2
```

There are other `TypeNameHandling` values you might want to use instead of `All` - see [the documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) for details.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, to apply @Daisy's answer to `Hangfire`, in your `StartUp` (this is for `.NET Core`):

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", ...);

app.UseHangfireServer(...);

JobHelper.SetSerializerSettings(new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For .Net core

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSerializerSettings(new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
            })
```